# "Some other reasons, e.g. technical or legal" or "e.g. technical or legal reasons"

Tags: nouns

In the following example:

> This could be motivated by some other reasons, e.g. *technical or legal*.

Is it correct to write "technical or legal" or shall one write "technical or legal reasons" or "technical or legal ones"?

Comment: Without more context it's hard to say. I would avoid "e.g." in formal writing. It might be more elegant to say, "This could be motivated by technical, legal or other reasons." Are you sure "motivated" is the right word?

Comment: @OldBrixtonian got it, thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the aim is to sound formal and polite, I would suggest omitting the abbreviation; *e.g.* and replacing it with either “for example", “for instance” or “such as”. There is no need to use the term *reasons* twice in such a short sentence and similarly, the pronoun "ones" can be omitted without any problem.

> This could be motivated by some other reasons such as technical or legal.